# How to add spaces and new lines when using json_encode()?

Tags: php, json

I've seen multiple answers in here but none of them had a solution to my question, so I made an account to ask this question. I understand now that `\n` is not an allowed character in json because the backslash is not allowed and that's why the problem is occurring.

I have the following code to encode an array in json:

```
<?php
$data = array('test1' => 'something1', 'test2' => 'something2', 'test3' => 'something3');
echo json_encode($data);
```

I'm trying to have the string outputted as follows:

> {
>
> "test1": "something1",
>
> "test2": "something2",
>
> "test3": "something3"
>
> }

But what I'm getting is this:

> {"test1":"something1","test2":"something2","test3":"something3"}

This is my go at it:

```
<?php
$data = array('test1' => 'something1\n', 'test2' => 'something2\n', 'test3' => 'something3\n');
echo json_encode($data);
```

but this returns

> {"test1":"something1\n","test2":"something2\n","test3":"something3\n"}

Comment: Do you want to show the response neat and clean somewhere?

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar Yes. That's the goal.

Comment: @DanielW. You're 100% correct. I must have missed that question because it exactly solves my problem. How do I mark my question as duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a second parameter to `json_encode`. This is called the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant:

```
<?php
$data = array('test1' => 'something1', 'test2' => 'something2', 'test3' => 'something3');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Pretty elegant solution! Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` with header

```
$data = array('test1' => 'something1', 'test2' => 'something2', 'test3' => 'something3');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

OR

```
$json= json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", $json);
```

Comment: What does that `header` do? @Daan's answer was the same as yours but without the header

Comment: @ILovePHP its telling that the data after this line header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); treated as json

Comment: Is that necessary to do when having pure PHP? Or is it something that should be done when having HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: @ILovePHP well daan solution is not working for me i am using PHP 7.1

Comment: @ILovePHP when you want to print the json in your desired format

Comment: That's odd. It works fine for me when using the same PHP version as you do.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is an interchange format, so you need not to be concerned about the looks very much.

Anyway, you can use [flag constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to alter the encoding process

```php
<?php

$a = '{"test1":"something1","test2":"something2","test3":"something3"}';
print_r(json_encode(json_decode($a, true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

See live example: https://3v4l.org/CEc3L